# The Indicative and Conditional mood in one sentence

Tags: grammar

I really found a wallet in the street some days ago. My friend takes me up for not having handed it over to the police at the same moment. How can he express his reproach?

My possible choices could be:

1. "If you found it, why wouldn't you have handed it over to the police?",
2. "If you found it, why shouldn't you have handed it over to the police?",
3. "If you found it, why wouldn't you hand it over to the police?",
4. "If you found it, why hadn't you have handed it over to the police?",
5. "If you found it, why haven't you have handed it over to the police?",
6. "If you found it, why didn't you hand it over to the police?".

Which of them are correct and which are grammatically impossible? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural, direct response—as far as I can tell—is #6: *"If you found it, why **didn't** you **hand** it over to the police?"*

I don't believe any of them are grammatically *impossible*.  The other options are legitimate sentences but (like so many aspects of the English language) they have subtleties that alter the meaning slightly.  For instance:

1. *"If you found it, why wouldn't you have handed it over to the police?"* – the asker is possibly asking about a situation that happened to someone else, and are asking why you would have resolved it differently to that person.  In this case, someone else found the wallet and *did* hand it in, and you have expressed that, if you were in that situation, you would not have done so.  The asker is asking why you would choose the opposite action, and there is an implication that they are surprised or disappointed by (or do not understand) your motives for keeping the wallet.
2. *"If you found it, why shouldn't you have handed it over to the police?"* – this is asking again in a hypothetical situation, but it suggests that you *did* hand it over to the police and asks if there is any reason that you can think of, why that might not have been the only reasonable action for a person in a similar situation.  It does not necessarily infer the surprise or lack of understanding of motives (that would depend on the tone of voice of the asker), it just asks what motives you can think of.
3. *"If you found it, why wouldn't you hand it over to the police?"* – again, a hypothetical situation, but one where *you* find the wallet and *don't* hand it over; it includes the implied suprise/lack of understanding but the asker is concentrating on why handing the wallet into the police is not the only reasonable action for *you*, specifically.  In casual spoken English, this might be used in place of #1, as it feels more natural to speak, and there would be differences in emphasis (e.g. on the first **you**) which would determine whether the asker meant the same as #1 or not.
4. *"If you found it, why hadn't you have handed it over to the police?"* – there's a past-tense, second-person flourish to this wording, that feels more like a sentence you would read in fictional writing, where the author is describing their surprise or disappointment of the actions of their narrator character, rather than a direct question to you in response to an event.  More-common variations of this exist in a first-person narrative, when the narrator questions their own motives (*"I found it, why hadn't I handed it over?"*) and in a third-person perspective, where a character is questioning the motives of another (*"If he found it, why hadn't he handed it over?"*).  Of all of them, this is the one that feels the most grammatically *awkward* (but not necessarily *wrong*, in certain contexts).  That said, the construction, *"Why hadn't you **have** handed it over"* isn't one I would use—but I'm not sure if the extra **have** is deliberate in your question, or a typing error.  If *not* a typing error, then I'd say *"hadn't you **have**"* was grammatically incorrect, in favour of *"If you found it, why hadn't you handed it over...?"*
5. *"If you found it, why haven't you have handed it over to the police?"* – this one suggests that you still have the wallet, and that you may (or may not) intend to hand it over to the police, and the asker is is asking why you haven't done that *yet*.  Again, the construction, *"haven't you **have**"* isn't one I would use—I'd simply say *"If you found it, why haven't you handed it over...?"*.  If the extra **have** was *not* a typing error, I would say this one is grammatically incorrect, also.
6. *"If you found it, why didn't you hand it over to the police?"* – this one best-answers the brief.  It implies that you *did* find it and *didn't* hand it over, and the asker is asking why you did not.  Whether or not the asker is surprised or disappointed is dependent on the tone of voice the asker uses, but it simply states two facts and asks for the reason without any narrative flourishes, so it is the one I would choose in most cases.

> **Comment:** I felt strong doubts about ##3,4. I should have written: "...why hadn't (haven't) you handed it over to the police". I think that in "...hadn't you have handed", the verb "have" looks grammatically impossible, doesn't it?

The sentence in #3 is fine, if that is what you intended to say.  Re-reading #4 and #5, I now see the extra **have** in those sentences.  I had originally considered them typing errors (which most native English readers will ignore when reading casually).  If the extra **have**s were *intentionally* included in your sentences then, yes, I would agree that these were grammatically incorrect.  *Without* the extra **have**s, those sentences are valid, at least in the forms I have tried to describe.

> **Comment:** I think I've gripped the meaning of all above versions but that of #1. I'll try to mull it over and adduce my way of understanding of #1

Sentences #1 and #2 are similar to each other, but may need an alternative examples to help clarify between those and #3.  Consider if your sentence we part of a conversation about *someone else* handing in a wallet.  The conversation may go:

> **Friend:** John found a wallet and handed it over to the police
>
> **You:** I wouldn't have done that, if I found it.
>
> **Friend:** *If you found it, why wouldn't you have handed it over to the police?*
>
> **You:** I am poor and need the money, so I wouldn't have handed it over.  I would have kept it.

In this case, you have suggested that, in the same situation as John, you would have done differently.  The question in #1 asks why you would have done differently.

In the case of #2, you don't necessarily need to be talking about a second person (and you might change **I** to **he** if you were).  Sticking strictly to the wording of option #2:

> **You** I found a wallet and handed it over to the police.  I shouldn't have done that.
>
> **Friend:** *If you found it, why shouldn't you have handed it over to the police?*
>
> **You:** I am poor and need the money. I should have kept it.

In this case, you have suggested that you regret the action that you took, and the question in #2 asks why that might be.

> **Comment**: From #1...Shouldn't we say:"If you had found a wallet, why wouldn't you have handed it to the police?"

I'd agree that the "If you had found..." phrasing is more correct (certainly when written down) but, as a listener, I'd accept the omission and fill in the missing **had**, subconciously, in the same way that I'd relate **it** to **the wallet**.

However, depending on the verbal stress that you can place on either **you** or **had**, you can change the implication of the sentence again:

- *"If **you** had found the wallet, why wouldn't you have handed it over..."* emphasises that the question is about why you would have done differently, given that someone else *did* find the wallet.
- *"If you **had** found the wallet, why wouldn't you have handed it over..."* would suggest that you were *looking* for the wallet and you *didn't* find it, but that your intention was to keep it anyway.  The question is asking why you wanted to keep it.

Even the construction, *"If you found it"*, as originally written, can also have different implications, depending on where the vocal stress is placed:

- Stressing the **if** reinforces the hypothetical nature of the question
- Stressing the **you** reinforces the fact that someone else already *did*
- Stressing the **found** reinforces both that you *did* find it *and* that the asker expected you to hand it in
- (Stressing the **it** may suggest that you don't know what the subject is, or that it was abstract, but that isn't the case here)

> **Comment:** And what if we are trying to convey the idea of reality in the if-clause?

I might use the alternative **since**, instead of **if**, if I were emphasising that something really *did* happen, i.e. *"**Since** you found it, why didn't you hand it in."*.  **Since** is effectively the same as **Given that**, and there is no longer any ambiguity as to whether or not something happened.

If I were trying to convey that both the reality *and* the time delay was significant to my question, I'd use **when**; i.e. *"**When** you found it, why didn't you hand it in?"*

> **Comment:** Can our initial main clause ("...why wouldn't you have handed it over to the police?) equal the meaning of "...why wouldn't it have occured to you to go up to the police and hand the wallet in?"

Yes, the two statements can be equal, but it may still depend on verbal stress.  Consider also:

- *"Why **wouldn't** you hand it over..."*
- *"Why wouldn't it **occur** to you to hand it over..."*
- *"Why didn't it **occur** to you to hand it over..."*

There is an element of incredulity implied by the verbal stress—that any *"normal"* person would have handed it over to the police.  All three of these may be framed as an attempt by the asker to coax or shame you into admitting that you knew what you were doing was wrong – perhaps as part of an interrogation.

If I were unambiguously trying to inform someone of the correct procedure, rather than determine or comment upon their morals (e.g. a part of an admonishment), I'd probably say *"When you found it, you should have handed it into the police."*

Comment: Jimbobmcgee, thank you very much!  I really haven't expected to get such a profound answer. When I re-examined my versions, I felt strong doubts about ##3,4. I should have written: "...why hadn't (haven't) you handed it over to the police". I think that in "...hadn't you have handed", the verb "have" looks grammatically impossible, doesn't it?

Comment: You've really enlightened me to a greater extent! I think I've gripped the meaning of all above versions but that of #1. I'll try to mull it over and adduce my way of understanding of #1.

Comment: @Eugene I've update the answer around #4 and #5 a little.  I initially misread what you had typed (formatting would have helped).  Of the six options, #4 and #5 have the chance of being grammatically incorrect, but it depends on whether the extra **have** in those sentences was a typing mistake or a deliberate entry into the question--when I first read them, my eyes skipped over them as a typing mistake, but I can see that they may have been designed to deliberately catch you out.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Shame on me for extra "have"-a typing error.

Comment: @Eugene.  Was it actually a typing error?  If you were asked this as a question and the *have*s were intentional, that may be the very point of the question you were asked.

Comment: Now I'm taking in what you infer from #1. There is the Conditional mood both in the main clause and in the Subordinate one? Shouldn't we say:"If you had found a wallet, why wouldn't you have handed it to the police?" when we refer the situation to the past? Or do we imagine that I may find a wallet without any time reference (hypothetically)?

Comment: And what if we are trying to convey the idea of reality in the if-clause? I really found a wallet yesterday and still have it in my hands, you see it and are interested (with a piece of reproachful advice) why I didn't have the slightest idea of coming over to a police office and handing the wallet in. In the other words, why  the idea of coming over to a police office wouldn't have come to my mind.

Comment: And thus, applying the above mentioned sense to our original situation: "If you found it (yesterday), why wouldn't it have occured to you to go up to the police and hand the wallet in?" Can our initial main clause ("...why wouldn't you have handed it over to the police?) equal the meaning of "...why wouldn't it have occured to you to go up to the police and hand the wallet in?".

Comment: sorry for not having noticed your question. It was really a typing error of my own).

Comment: @Eugene - updated the answer to try and address "If you had found..."

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't come into my mind to give a steadfast gaze an interchange between "if" and "when". I often stumble across a hindrance to expressing a thought in English whereas I can easily evince it in my synthetic language by simply trifling with the word order, shifting of tenses, using extra particles. I can also convey the idea of unreality with an air of reproach, admonishment and so on effectively by using the Infinitive constructions, changing affirmative forms into negative. And there is no such notion in my language as "sequence of tences" (time shift).

Comment: And therefore as far as modal verbs, the Subjunctive and Conditional mood are concerned I encounter difficulties with ultimate understanding of the negatives. For example, I grip the tints of the meaning of :"He could have handed in the wallet to the police when he found it" in two possible ways.   1. It is very likely that he handed in the wallet.  2. He would have been able to hand the wallet in but he hasn't done so.

Comment: But I can't say for sure whether I'd correctly apprehend: "He couldn't have handed in the wallet to the police when he found it".

Comment: I erroneously typed about the "gaze". I meant "...to give a steadfast gaze to an interchange...", sorry.